# wordpress plugins using Jquery not functioning

Tags: jquery

I used a wordpress plugin called jquery updater and it broke the functionality of all the plugins that use jquery.  How do I fix the jquery functionality to use my plugins again? For example,

http://www.stratumplans.com/nqdc/

I am testing the collapse-o-matic plugin. Where you see the drop down carrot, there should be a title that expands into text.  Does not work.

I get these errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cufon is not defined www.stratumplans.com/:296
anonymous function)

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' collapse.min.js?         ver=1.5.2:1
(anonymous function) collapse.min.js?ver=1.5.2:1
l jquery.min.js:2
.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
v.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
A

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' gprofiles.js?     ver=2013Augaa:2
Gravatar.init gprofiles.js?ver=2013Augaa:2
(anonymous function) wpgroho.js?ver=3.5.2:32
e.resolveWith jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.C
```

I have deactived all plugins and then tried the one. I have researched but not sure if I understand what could be at the root of it. I have re-installed WP. I have looked at other stack postings but not sure if they apply to my situation.  I am not adept at programming but with good explanation I learn quickly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. you have jquery included twice, dunno if this is necessary
2. you are missing cufon, add this after jquery:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cufon/1.09i/cufon-yui.js"/>`